# Hibernate doesn't recognize reverse engineering strategy file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

in my Java Spring Boot project I generate entities using hibernate-tools-maven plugin. I need to customize some entities so I defined my strategy in a certain class and according with [official plugin documentation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/main/maven/README.md) I imported it inside the pom, but at runtime it throws this error:

> Execution default-cli of goal org.hibernate.tool:hibernate-tools-maven:6.4.4.Final:hbm2java failed: An exporter of class 'project.api.domain.customstrategy.CustomStrategy' could not be created.

In debug mode I found out that this is due to the ClassNotFound exception.

This is my pom configuration for reveng strategy:

```
<revengStrategy>project.api.domain.customstrategy.CustomStrategy</revengStrategy>
```

According to the doc, the tag < revengStrategy > must contain:

> The class name of the reverse engineering strategy to use. Extend the
> DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy and override the corresponding methods,
> e.g. to adapt the generate class names or to provide custom type mappings.

It seems that it doesn't recognize the class, but I don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Thanks.